# json regex error

Tags: json, regex

I wrote a json regex for url redirection validation

```
"redirect_uri": {
        "type": "string",
        "pattern": "^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,8})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$",
        "description":"Application redirect_uri"
      },
```

I am getting this error

illegal backslash escape sequence in string, at character offset 1223 (before "\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-...")

Where I am making mistakes . Everything seems to be fine to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's satisfy your pattern requirement but this is a valid JSON:

```
"redirect_uri": {
    "type": "string",
    "pattern": "^(https?:\/\/)?([\\da-z\\.-]+)\\.([a-z\\.]{2,8})([\\/\\w \\.-]*)*\\/?$",
    "description": "Application redirect_uri"
}
```

I just add some escape \ where needed.
I recommend to use some online JSON validator site like: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Just for testing: Don't forget to set a `{` at the beginning and a `}` at the end.

Comment: Totally right! I tried to stay closest as possible to the question I guess ;)